# CI 3 extend user agent cannot access auto loaded models

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following file in application/libraries/MY_User_agent.php. When I try to access an autoloaded mode I get a php noticed

Message: `Undefined property: Login::$Appconfig`.

If I access this from a regular controller or regular library it will work; but somehow being in this sub class or even another library that is extended the models don't seem available. If I manually load model it will work.

```
class MY_User_agent extends CI_User_agent 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->Appconfig->get('test');
        $CI->load->library('Mobile_Detect');
        $this->detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, because classes that you autoload are instantiated before the controller (and a controller instance is what `get_instance()` returns).

And you shouldn't do that anyway, because libraries are not supposed to depend on models, nor any part of the application.